Type-mismatch Error Unable to ingest a value which contain hexadecimal value in bigquery
For column "csirsconfig" we are facing value mismatch issue.
Here in CSV file  value of  column "csirsconfig"   is “3F” but in BQ table its loading as “3.0”.   data type of column “csirsconfig"   is string in csv which is Hexadecimal at source side.
I tried with  casting as HEX_STRING but it didn’t work.
we are processing csv file using apache spark and loading in Bigquery table

Maybe describe the schema for the table.  Maybe provide a sample of a CSV row.  Maybe show the statement/operation you are using to load the CSV.  Maybe show an example of what the result in the table looks like after loading.
